# AngularJS Change ahref without Target

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, I need to define the target of all ahref and set it to _self only if the target is not defined. Would this be done through a directive in AngularJS or another way?

I currently have this:

```
angular.element("a").prop("target", "_self");
```

But it changes everything, even if the target is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you've written would set the target for `<a>` tags that existed at the time that code was run.  If you create a directive, then it will be applied to any `<a>` tags that are added later.

It is possible to write a directive for a regular html element like `<a>`, so you wouldn't necessarily have to annotate it in any extra way.  You should be careful about where you put such a directive since it potentially changes the standard behaviour of an element, but it would work for your situation.

```
myModule
.directive('a', function() {
    restrict : 'E',
    link : function(scope, el, attrs) {
        if( !attrs.target ) {
            el.prop('target', '_self');
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to edit existing code:

```
var elements = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));

  angular.forEach(elements,function(element) {
          if(!angular.element(element).prop('target')) {
                 angular.element(element).prop('target',"_self")
           }
  });
```

It's preferable to use a directive

```
angular.module("app", [])
.directive("setTarget", function() {
    return {
        "restrict" : "EAC",
        "link" : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if(!attrs.target) {
             attrs.$set("target", "_self");   
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<a href="#" set-target>link</a>
```

Comment: I choose the answer below because this answer although correct would require me to add set-target to element.